# How to get a count via a subselect

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write an SQL which gets the number of rows in a table which has the same value as a specific column.
In this case, the table has a column called 'title'. For each row I return, along with the value of other columns for the row, I want to get the number of rows in the table which have the same value as that row's 'title' value. 
For now, the best I have is:
select firstname, lastname, city, state, title, (select count from myTable where title = title);

Obviously, all this gives me is the number of rows in the table in my subselect.
How do I get the  right side of the title = to refer to the value of the column's title?

Thanks for any help, anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called "correlated subquery". It goes like this:

```
select firstname, lastname, title, 
              (select count(1) from table where title=a.title) title_count 
from table a;
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, Srini. If there's any way I can add more points to you, let me know: this helped out immensely!

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but I think that it should work for what you are trying to do

```
WITH titles AS (
    SELECT
        Title
        , COUNT(*) AS Occurences
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY Title
)
SELECT 
    t1.FirstName
    , t1.LastName
    , t1.City
    , t1.state
    , t1.title
    , titles.Occurences
FROM myTable AS t1
INNER JOIN titles ON t1.Title = titles.Title
```

Comment: This looks like it would be using the same general pattern as Srini's solution, but I'm not quite sure: I'll have to try it out. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the window/analytic functions.  If you are using one of these (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, for example), you can do this as:

```
select t.firstname, t.lastname, t.title, t.city, t.state,
       count(*) over (partition by title) as numwithtitle
from t
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, but I'm not using one of those DB engines.

Comment: @charlest . . . when you ask a question, you should include the database you are using.

Comment: Excellent point. I'm using sqlite. I'll remember to add that in next time. Thank you for taking the time to answer.